# Custom Shape Dialog

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-alertdialog

[image: Custom Background]

I want a activity in this shape..i applied dialog theme th this in manifest,but how to make this image as my dialog shape

My activity is

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.success);

    }
```

My xml is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_dialog">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/success"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:text="You have successfully signed in with LinkedIn"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/dia_text"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/personalise"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/success"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="Lets, personalise Conext!"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/dia_text_con"
                android:textSize="22sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/nextBtn"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/personalise"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/next_icon" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I.m new to android,Sorry if my question is too silly.Can you please help me

my Mamifest

```
 <activity
        android:name=".ui.SuccessPopUp"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.Dialog" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your activity is your dialog, you must create a custom dialog theme. Add the following lines in `styles.xml`.

```
<resources>
<style name="MyDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:background">#00000000</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Change the theme in the manifest file also.

```
 <activity
    android:name=".ui.SuccessPopUp"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@android:@style/MyDialogTheme" />
```

Finally change the background of the layout to your image and remove the second RelativeLayout.

Comment: can you please elaborate

Comment: Why and where should i use --> final Dialog d = new Dialog(this,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
        d.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
        return d;

Comment: This must he used in the Java class where you want to show the dialog. Here you are implementing a custom dialog with transparent background and a custom ContentView.

Comment: I'm really confused,So what you are saying is that even though i have applied dialog theme in the manifest,I have to do the above line..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149962/discussion-between-anitha-sundaramurthy-and-abhi).